# How to filter and delete rows of data based on user-specified date?

Tags: excel, vba

I have data to filter based on the start date and end date.

The Start and End date have their own columns in, "Master Publisher Content." 
Start date is in column `G` and End date is in column `H`.

I'm trying to filter and delete the rows of data based on a user-specified date range on the "Enter Info" tab, the user-specified start date is in cell `C2` and the user-specified end date is in cell `E2`.

For example, if cell `C2` is `April 1st, 2019` and cell `E2` is `April 30th, 2019` I want to delete the rows of data that are not between these dates.

This code is just working with the end date. It says no cells were found.

```
Public Sub DeleteRowsWithAutofilterDates()

    Dim wksData As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim StartDate As Range
    Dim EndDate As Range

    'Set references up-front
    Set wksData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Publisher Content")
    Set StartDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter Info").Range("C2")
    Set EndDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter Info").Range("E2")

    'Identify the last row and use that info to set up the Range
    With wksData
        lngLastRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngData = .Range("G2:G" & lngLastRow)
    End With

    '------------------------------------------------------------
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With rngData
        'Apply the Autofilter method to the first column of
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<=EndDate"

        'Delete the visible rows while keeping the header
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete
    End With

    '----------------------------------------------------------------

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Turn off the AutoFilter
    With wksData
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        If .FilterMode = True Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With

    'Let the user know the rows have been removed
    MsgBox "Damn son! Rows removed."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the value of the cell's relating to the start and end date, not the range itself. take `Dim StartDate As Range` and `Dim EndDate As Range` and make them `Dim StartDate As Date` and `Dim EndDate As Date`.

After that change `Set StartDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter Info").Range("C2")`
to `StartDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter Info").cells(2, "C").value`
And `Set EndDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter Info").Range("E2")` to `EndDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter Info").cells(2, "E").value`

This will get you the value of the cell instead of its range.

`lngLastRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` Should be `lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).row`

I'm not sure how many rows you will be going through but actually deleting can be pretty slow if you have a lot, so this will clear the row and then sort.

```
    Dim wksData As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date

    Dim tDate As Date
    Dim iter As Long

    Set wksData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Publisher Content")

    StartDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter Info").Cells(2, "C").value
    EndDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter Info").Cells(2, "E").value

    With wksData
        lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).row

        For iter = 2 To lngLastRow
            if .Cells(iter, "G").value = "" or isnull(.Cells(iter, "G").value) then
                .Rows(iter) = ""
            else
                tDate = .Cells(iter, "G").value

                If tDate < StartDate Or tDate > EndDate Then
                    .Rows(iter) = ""
                End If
            end if
        Next
        LastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column
        .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lngLastRow, LastCol)).Sort key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End With
```

Comment: thanks so much for your time, I appreciate it! 

I seem to be getting a "Type Mismatch error" from the following line of code:


tDate = .Cells(iter, "G").Value

Comment: Could it be the way, the date is formatted? So far i've tried DD/MM/YYYY and MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: Do all the cells in column "G" have values that are dates? An empty cell or a string not formatted as a date would throw an error. The actual date format should not matter you could do MM/DD/YYYY, DD-MM-YY, etc. it should have no problem with those.

Comment: Some cells in Column G are blank, I would like to delete the rows where the cells are blank. All of the cells in column G and H are formatted as MM/DD/YYYY but appear as "Month Day, Year"

Comment: @Alex Just edited in a check for blanks, that should stop the error.